# Starting activity with a new flag

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I start activity with a new flag? I have 2 activities. One is main and other one I used for displaying database in `ListView`. It consists of address and (latitude,longitude) values. I'm trying that whenever I click an item control should go to the main activity and show that (latitude,longitude) values there on map. I passed the (latitude,longitude) values in a bundle and wrote a `set()` in main activity to set the (lat,lon) values. But the main activity is running in background. My code in the 2nd activity is:

```
    Intent i1=new Intent(Display.this,Cortes.class);
    Bundle b11=new Bundle();

    b11.putDouble(q, b1);
    b11.putDouble(r, c1);
    //b11.putBoolean("flag", flag);
    i1.putExtras(b11);
    i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i1);
```

Here b1,c1 are (latitude,longitude) values and `Cortes` is main activity and `Display` is 2nd activity. My code in main activity is:

```
public void set()
{     
  bun=getIntent().getExtras();
  q=bun.getDouble("q");
  r=bun.getDouble("r");
  GeoPoint new1=new GeoPoint((int)(q*1000000), (int)(r*10000000));    
  mc.setCenter(new1);

  mapOverlays = mv.getOverlays();

  OverlayItem overlayitem =    new OverlayItem(new1, "New", "test1");
  itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
  mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
  mc.animateTo(new1); 
  mv.setSatellite(false);
  mc.setCenter(new1);
  mv.postInvalidate();
}
```

Is there any way to call `set()` from 2nd activity? Or how should I call it when the main activity is called from 2nd activity? Also I want to start main activity with a new flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure main activity flag is "singleTop".

```
Intent init = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
init.putExtra(Putwhatever you want to put);
init.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
startActivity(init);
```

override onNewIntent method in MainActivity. You will get intent "init" which will passed as a parameter to onNewIntent method.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem in starting the activity. In bundle you need to fetch values like this:

```
Bundle var_name = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle(key);
```

Comment: thanks but how to start activity with a new flag and call the set(). pls suggest some idea and post some link pls

Comment: start activity like this:   Intent launch = new Intent(youractivity.this, activitytobelauched.class);     launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(launch);

Comment: my main activity is still running in background. i want to launch that activity with new flag with new latitude,longitude values that i passed from 2nd activity. how can i do that. pls help suggest some method

Comment: use this flag:FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP